# Detaching item touch helper callback from recycler view

Tags: android

How do I go about doing this for a swipe action for items in a recycler view?

This is my item touch helper class:

```
public class RecyclerTouchHelper extends ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback {

    private final RecyclerTouchHelperListener listener;
    boolean swipeAllowed;
    private static final String TAG = RecyclerTouchHelper.class.getSimpleName();

    public RecyclerTouchHelper(int dragDirs, int swipeDirs, RecyclerTouchHelperListener listener, boolean swipeAllowed) {
        super(dragDirs, swipeDirs);
        this.listener = listener;
        this.swipeAllowed = swipeAllowed;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMove(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSelectedChanged(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int actionState) {
        if (viewHolder != null) {
            final View foregroundView = ((MealPlanAdapter.MealPlanDetailsViewHolder) viewHolder).foregroundView;
            getDefaultUIUtil().onSelected(foregroundView);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildDrawOver(@NonNull Canvas c, @NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, float dX, float dY, int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive) {
        final View foregroundView = ((MealPlanAdapter.MealPlanDetailsViewHolder) viewHolder).foregroundView;
        getDefaultUIUtil().onDrawOver(c, recyclerView, foregroundView, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
    }

    @Override
    public void clearView(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
        final View foregroundView = ((MealPlanAdapter.MealPlanDetailsViewHolder) viewHolder).foregroundView;
        getDefaultUIUtil().clearView(foregroundView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildDraw(@NonNull Canvas c, @NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, float dX, float dY, int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive) {
        final View foregroundView = ((MealPlanAdapter.MealPlanDetailsViewHolder) viewHolder).foregroundView;
        getDefaultUIUtil().onDraw(c, recyclerView, foregroundView, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSwiped(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
        listener.onSwiped(viewHolder, direction, viewHolder.getAbsoluteAdapterPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isItemViewSwipeEnabled() {
        return swipeAllowed;
    }

    @Override
    public int convertToAbsoluteDirection(int flags, int layoutDirection) {
        return super.convertToAbsoluteDirection(flags, layoutDirection);
    }

    public interface RecyclerTouchHelperListener {
        void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction, int position);
    }
}
```

And this is a function in the fragment/activity that is triggered via an action from the recycler adapter:

```
ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback itemTouchHelperCallback;

@Override
public void onScrollCheck(boolean allowSwipe) {
    if (!allowSwipe) {
        itemTouchHelperCallback = new RecyclerTouchHelper(0, 0, this, false);
        itemTouchHelperCallback = null;
        new ItemTouchHelper(itemTouchHelperCallback).attachToRecyclerView(null);
    } else {
        itemTouchHelperCallback = new RecyclerTouchHelper(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT, this, true);
        new ItemTouchHelper(itemTouchHelperCallback).attachToRecyclerView(mealplanRecycler);
    }
}
```

My problem is that no matter what I do, once swiping is turned on it remains allowed and I cannot turn it off. Is it something I am doing wrong when defining and assigning the callback?

Answer (score 0):

Where are you setting `swipeAllowed` back to false?

You seem to be setting it `true` first time round and then keep hitting

```
else {
        itemTouchHelperCallback = new RecyclerTouchHelper(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT, this, true);
        new ItemTouchHelper(itemTouchHelperCallback).attachToRecyclerView(mealplanRecycler);
    }
```

As it was never set back to false?

Comment: It's in the onScrollCheck function I included in the 2nd block of code above. There is a boolean action sent from the adapter. If it's false then I set it to false `itemTouchHelperCallback = new RecyclerTouchHelper(0, 0, this, false);`